# Is there any "Personal" Finance app that allows 2 administrators?

Tags: budget, family, 529-plan, online-applications

I'm an advocate of marriage meaning together in everything.

Sometimes even work. But i've had some trouble finding a "Personal" finance app that would allow me to make shared budgeting and allow input from several users.

It's somewhat like a google docs stuff for finance. I've been using doodle spreadsheets since shareability with my wife is the utmost important feature.

Comment: is it important to have distinct users and track what each one does? Otherwise - there's no meaning to "several users", you can just use the same login. User access is needed only for audit purposes or restriction settings - both features aren't usually needed for *personal* finance programs.

Comment: The thing is we might be using 2 computers at the same time while creating our budget and wouldn't like the app getting locked as a security meassure or anything like that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We use [YNAB](http://www.youneedabudget.com) to handle our household budget - their latest version allows cloud sync between Android/iOS devices and various desktop installs.  I have the budget folder shared with my wife's Dropbox account so we both an view the budget, enter spending, and make changes.

Comment: Great, does it work with any currency?

Comment: I don't know about any currency, since I Just use it in USD but I do know that they support many currencies.  There may be a listing on the web site.

Answer (score 3):

We use mint for just that. We have a "shared" account. We each have the mobile app and share the same pin for the application (not our phones -- you can set a pin in the settings on the application).

Thus we each share a login to the site, where we have setup all of our accounts. In the "Your Profile" link at the top of the page, you may select the Email & Alerts option. From here you may add a second e-mail account. This way if you go over a budget or have a bill upcoming each of you will get a notification.

We have setup budgeting through the web site, and either of us can modify the budget via logging in.

Answer (score 1):

The best solution I've been able to find for this is [MoneyWiz](http://www.silverwiz.com), where both are logged into the same sync account.